# Is initialization vector part of Output ESP packet in IPsec?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, ipsec

[image: ESP Packet showing initialization vector as part of output packet]

Encryption Algorithm: AES-CBC
Authentication Algorithm: HMAC-SHA1-96

Is it necessary that in ESP, initialization vector be always the part of output packet.
If no, what are those algorithms ?
If yes, Why in some of the images on google/books show esp packet with no iv field ?
[image: ESP PACKET FORMAT]

Comment: I think this is off-topic here, maybe try [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [RFC-2406, section 2.3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2406.html#section-2.3) (emphasis mine):

> Payload Data is a variable-length field containing data described by
> the Next Header field. The Payload Data field is mandatory and is an
> integral number of bytes in length.  **If the algorithm used to encrypt
> the payload requires cryptographic synchronization data, e.g., an
> Initialization Vector (IV), then this data MAY be carried explicitly
> in the Payload field**.  Any encryption algorithm that requires such
> explicit, per-packet synchronization data MUST indicate the length,
> any structure for such data, and the location of this data as part of
> an RFC specifying how the algorithm is used with ESP. If such
> synchronization data is implicit, the algorithm for deriving the data
> MUST be part of the RFC.

So the initialization vector presence is conditional and depends on particular encryption algorithm.